# Expression must be a modifiable L value error

Tags: c++

I am writing a code that reads a ppm file and stores the width, the height and the pixels of the file to an image object. In my image class I have a pointer that holds the image data. I also have an error in a method that sets the rgb values for a x, y pixel.

```
 typedef load compontent_t 
 class Image
 {
 public:
 enum channel_t { RED = 0, GREEN, BLUE };          
 protected:
 component_t * buffer;                        //! Holds the image data.

 unsigned int width,             //! The width of the image (in pixels)
 height;                        //! The height of the image (in pixels)


// data mutators

/*! Sets the RGB values for an (x,y) pixel.
 *
 *  The method should perform any necessary bounds checking.
 *
 *  \param x is the (zero-based) horizontal index of the pixel to set.
 *  \param y is the (zero-based) vertical index of the pixel to set.
 *  \param value is the new color for the (x,y) pixel.
 */
 void setPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, Color & value) {
 if (x > 0 && x < width && y > 0 && y < height) {
 size_t locpixel = y*width + x;
 size_t componentofpixel = locpixel * 3;
 *buffer + componentofpixel = value.r;
 *buffer + componentofpixel + 1 = value.g;
 *buffer + componentofpixel + 2 = value.b;    
  }
 else {
 cout << "Pixel out of bounds" << endl;
  }
 }


Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height,  component_t * data_ptr): width(width), height(height),buffer(data_ptr) {}
```

So in the setPixel method when i am trying to find the correct spot of the buffer to set the rgb value it shows me the error: "expression must be a modifiable L value"

Comment: When using pointer arithmetic to access a buffer, my advice is *don't*. Use normal array indexing. That will solve your problem. And as a hint to your problem, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: That was the answer, but on an unrelated note, the code contradicts the comments for x=0 or y=0, which should be in bounds.